# Central limit theorem for sum from varied distributions

Tags: central-limit-theorem

The central limit theorem as I am familiar with it applies to the limiting (rescaled) distribution of $n$ convolutions of a single probability distribution as $n$ goes to infinity, or equivalently, to distribution one gets from taking a sum of $n$ random variables each with a single fixed distribution. That is, it is a theorem about the (limiting as $n\to \infty$) probability distribution of
$A_1 + A_2 + ... + A_n$ where each term has a fixed distribution $P$.

I am asking about a theorem about the limiting probability distribution of
$A_1 + A_2 + ... + A_n$
where $A_1$ has probability distribution $P_1$, $A_2$ has probability distribution $P_2$, $A_3$ has probability distribution $P_3$, etc.

Also, is there a theorem for the case where each distribution isn't fixed, but is selected at random with probability determined by a measure $\mu$?

Is there such a general theorem, where the limit isn't necessarily gaussian, the limit can be reconstructed from $\mu$, and the convergence is pretty strong?

Comment: Could you give more details for your second question? How do you define selection of distribution at random with probability determined by measure $\mu$?

Comment: I've introduced latex and changed some sentences, please check if this is ok.

Comment: what constitutes "pretty strong" convergence? Are you asking about bounds?

Comment: I suppose I was really just trying to avoid a theorem that gives convergence in such a weak sense that, while technically true, it has little application, e.g. pointwise converence almost everywhere.

Comment: if you are talking about convergence of distribution functions, then convergence pointwise almost everywhere (on the continuity points to be more precise) is called weak convergence or convergence in distribution and is the most applied type of convergence, since all the assymptotic statistics are based on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [theorem 3.1](http://books.google.com/books?id=4LkdSaI4xXMC&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3a%22Valentin%20Vladimirovich%20Petrov%22&hl=fr&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q&f=false) in this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=4LkdSaI4xXMC&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3A%22Valentin%20Vladimirovich%20Petrov%22&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) answers your first question. The key restriction in central limit theorem is not different distributions but the independence. The result is a very nice one, since it says that for interesting sums of  independent random variables the limiting distribution has to have certain property, namely [infinite divisibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_%28probability%29). The classical central limit theorem (with iid variables with finite variances) is then only a very special case of this theorem.

Note that this is a very general answer to very general question. Given the nature of your distributions more precise answer can be given. For example if the distributions  satisfy [Lindeberg's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) then the limiting distribution is necessary normal (if we exclude let us say non-interesting cases).

Comment: What do you mean by interesting and non-interesting cases?

Comment: @Ashok, interesting cases are where condition of infinite smallness is satisfied. Naturally you can consider that the interesting cases are where this condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Very interesting. Is the theorem you cite effectively the theorem loosely summarized in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_%28probability%29#Limit_theorem) you cited. I don't have access to that book, especially at a retail of $250. :)

Comment: The wikipedia summary is quite loose, as there must clearly be more required or there are requirements on the members of the triangular array that aren't stated there, otherwise you could take two such triangular arrays with different limits and interchange every other row with the result that now neither one converges (even though the wikipedia article _sounds_ like it says they should)

Comment: @John, the access in the google books is not enough? You might get access to the book via library you know, it is old-fashioned way, but it works :)

Comment: @John, the theorem 3.1 is also stated for triangular arrays, only infinite smallness is needed. If you want the conditions when the convergence happens, they are stated in [theorem 3.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=4LkdSaI4xXMC&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3A%22Valentin%20Vladimirovich%20Petrov%22&hl=fr&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: So is infinite divisibility and convergence is the most you can get? Infinite divisibility sounds like a pretty weak restraint e.g. take the fourier transform, take an nth (complex) root, now take the reverse fourier transform and call it h, then h convoluted with itself n times gives your original - so the only restriction is that h needs to be only non-negatively valued (should automatically have area 1). Or am I missing something? I could well have made a mistake there.

Comment: @John, your question was about the limiting distribution of certain sum of random variables. It can be understood in two ways: a) you are asking what types of limiting distributions there are _when limit exists_ b) you are asking when does the sequence converge. My answer is for a) from the comments I gather you are interested in b) also. Then my previous comment applies.

Comment: @John, I am not sure that I follow. If the sum of random variables satisfying infinite smallness converges, then the limiting distribution is infinitely divisible. That is very strong result, since infinitely divisible distributions have unique characterisation.

Comment: It sounds like your answer is both correct and about as good as is possible. Thanks for all your excellent comments.

Answer (score 0):

mpiktas gave a very good technical answer.

There's a nice simulation of this here:

http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/sampling_dist/index.html

You can manipulate the distribution at the top of this demo to show a combination of different distributions (such as bimodal), and the distribution of sample means will still be normal.